# How can I scroll to the top on page change using AngularUI Bootstrap's pagination?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am developing a SPA using AngularJS 1.3.11 and AngularUI Bootstrap 0.12.0 have the following pagination which works well and as expected.

```
<pagination total-items="incidentCount"
            items-per-page="limit"
            ng-model="currentPage"
            max-size="5"
            boundary-links="true"
            previous-text="&lsaquo;"
            next-text="&rsaquo;"
            first-text="&laquo;"
            last-text="&raquo;">
</pagination>
```

I would like to have this pagination at the bottom of the page and scroll to the top every time the user changes pages (either by selecting a page number or using the navigation arrows).

How might I go about adding this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-change` directive and `write a method` to go to the `top` place.

**HTML**

```
<a name="top"></a>
Para1
para2
...
...
...
para n

<pagination ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.pageChanged = function() {
   window.location.hash = '#top';
};
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqa9o75wFliqjHddKEjY?p=preview

Comment: I ended up using your idea of `ng-change='pageChanged()'`, but instead of using an anchor, I used `window.scrollTo(0,0)`.

Comment: Ok fine..but anchor solution is better if you want to target particular para..anyway enjoy :)

Comment: scrollto is better, because the hash value messes with angular routing

Answer (score 2):

Asiks solutions just works the first time. You need to inject the **$location** och **$anchorscroll** to your controller.

**HTML**

```
<pagination ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.pageChanged = function() {
    $location.hash('top');
    $anchorScroll();
};
```

Comment: This worked great for me. Up vote for the great solution cause the accepted answer from @Asik does not work correctly and should not have been selected as correct. This solutions works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have some elements in a scrollable element like **div** , **section** or... you can use this directive to go top of your element with animate.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scrollable" scroll-to-top="students">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in students">{{student.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**style:**

```
.scrollable {
   height: 400px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('scrollToTop', ['$log', function ($log) {
   return {
      scope: {
         scrollToTop: "="
      },
      link: function (scope, element) {
         scope.$watchCollection('scrollToTop', function () {
            $(element).animate({scrollTop: 0},500);
         });
      }
   };

}]);
```